# How can I hide the background applications menu in GNOME?

Tags: gnome-shell

Is it possible to place the background applications menu somewhere else? I'd prefer if it wasn't in the way of the desktop, but still easily accessible elsewhere. If not, is there at least a way to hide it?

[image: background apps menu]

As you can see, when it's closed it still protrudes onto the desktop in the bottom-left:

[image: background apps menu still protrudes when closed]

I've looked in the system settings, as well as GNOME Tweak Tool, but I can't find any settings for it. I also haven't found any GNOME extensions to solve the problem.

#### Specs

- Ubuntu 17.04
- GNOME Shell 3.24.1
- Arc Theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some extensions you may try.

1. [TopIcons:](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons/) It places those icons at the top bar.
2. [TopIcons Plus:](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/) Same as above, but with more customisations.
3. [Hide Legacy Tray:](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/967/hide-legacy-tray/) It just hides the tray containing those icons.